# CSS how center inputs

Tags: html, css

I have something like this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKYNLN)

How can I make inputs to be always in center in `div .cont` and labels on left and right side. No mater how long labels will be. I don't know how long label will be and how much sets will be. (one set I mean label, input, input and label)

Code:

```css
.site {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cont {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: table;
}

input {
  max-width: 50px;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.lab {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="cont">
    <form>
      <label>sasadsadas</label>
      <input type="number">
      <input type="number">
      <label class="lab">sasasdssadsa</label><br>
      <label>sasas</label>
      <input type="number">
      <input type="number">
      <label class="lab">sasdsadsa</label><br>
      <label>sasssas</label>
      <input type="number">
      <input type="number">
      <label class="lab">sasasdsaadsa</label><br>
      <label>sasaas</label>
      <input type="number">
      <input type="number">
      <label class="lab">sasasdsadsadsa</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time try to use build in code snippet, it is easier to copy code to answer and play with it. It have a similar functionality like codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wrapper 50%, so on every line you have two div's.

Select odd div's `.wrap` and set float's or flex or whatever you want for positioning content in left wrap's.

Do similar things for right wrappers and viola.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}


/* left */
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n+1) { 
  background: orange;
}
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n+1) label{float:left;}
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n+1) input{float:right;}

/* right */
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: pink;
}
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n) input {float:left;}
.wrap:nth-of-type(2n) label {float:right;}


/* old setup */

.site {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cont {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: table;
}

input {
  max-width: 30px;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="cont">
    <form>
      <div class="wrap">
        <label>ssasadsadas</label>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <input type="number">
        <label>sasasdsffdsadsa</label>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <label>sdsadas</label>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <input type="number">
        <label>sadsa</label>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <label>sasadsxsddadas</label>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <input type="number">
        <label>sadssadsa</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="cont">
    <form>
      <div class="container">
        <label>sasadsadas</label>
        <input type="number">
        <input type="number">
        <label class="lab">sasasdssadsa</label>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <label>sasas</label>
        <input type="number">
        <input type="number">
        <label class="lab">sasdsadsa</label>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <label>sasssas</label>
        <input type="number">
        <input type="number">
        <label class="lab">sasasdsaadsa</label>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <label>sasaas</label>
        <input type="number">
        <input type="number">
        <label class="lab">sasasdsadsadsa</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```